# NetSuite - How to loop thru context newRecord objects when using User Event Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

When utilizing a `User Event` Script, I am attempting to loop through a `context` object to find all `newRecord` objects that are selected by a user in the Inventory `Print` screen. I am able to retrieve a single record within the context object, however, if a user selects multiple invoices to print, I am unable to retrieve the additional invoices.

When looking at the Execution log, I am unable to see the entire `context` object.

[image: Invoice Selection]

[image: Invoice Rendering]

My script is as follows:

> /** @NApiVersion 2.0 @NScriptType UserEventScript
> */
>
> define(['N/record'], function (record) {          function
> beforeLoad(context) {
>
> ```
>   try {
>
>       var arrInvoiceIds= []
>       var arrFileNames= []
>
>       var r = context.newRecord
>       var nrf = r.getFields()
>       
>       //fetch invoice record
>     var invoiceRecord = record.load({ type: record.Type.INVOICE, id: r.id })
>       
>       for(var i=0; i < nrf.length; i++){
>         
>         var customerName = ""
>         var invNo = ""
>         var fileName = ""
>         
>         if(nrf[i] == "entity"){
>           customerName = invoiceRecord.getValue('entity');
>         }
>         if(nrf[i] == "tranid"){
>           invNo = invoiceRecord.getValue('tranid');
>         }
>         
>         if(customerName != "" && invNo != ""){
>           fileName = customerName + "_" + invNo;
>         }
>         
>         
>         
>       }
>
>       log.debug ({
>           title: 'r.id',
>           details: r.id //arrInvoiceIds //arrFileNames
>       });
>     
>     log.debug ({
>           title: 'nrf',
>           details: nrf //arrInvoiceIds //arrFileNames
>       });
>     
>     log.debug ({
>           title: 'nrf.length',
>           details: nrf.length //arrInvoiceIds //arrFileNames
>       });
>     
>     log.debug ({
>           title: 'context',
>           details: context //arrInvoiceIds //arrFileNames
>       });
>     log.debug ({
>           title: 'file',
>           details: fileName //arrInvoiceIds //arrFileNames
>       });
>
>   } catch (e) {
>
>       log.error ({ 
>           title: e.name,
>           details: e.message
>       });  
>
>   }
> }
>
> return {
>   beforeLoad: beforeLoad      
> }; });
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print multiple invoices, the UserEvent is simply triggered multiple times. You should see that in your logs. The invoices are not combined on a single instance of context within a single UserEvent.